# Why do we get NULL as a side effect in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

The data and code below is from the ??data.table and example(data.table).

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
DT[2:5,cat(v,"\n")]        # just for j's side effect

2 3 4 5 
NULL
```

I do not understand why we get NULL after cat(v). 
Are we able to not get NULL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get `NULL` because the expression at the `j` position of data table, i.e., `cat` returns `NULL` and thus you get a `NULL` value returned and since there is no variable to capture the value, it will be printed in the console by default. If you don't want it to get printed, you can assign it to a variable:

```
x <- DT[2:5, cat(v, "\n")]
# 2 3 4 5 
x
# NULL
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I'm confused why we get 2,3,4,5 in the first place.. Could you also give a brief explanation on that please?

Comment: You get 2,3,4,5 because of the side effect of cat function. You specified 2:5 at the i position of data table which means cat will print out vector v at index 2:5 and this in your case is 2,3,4,5.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get it

Comment: @Darren This is a side effect of exactly how `data.table`'s `[]` prints, see some issues ([1](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/482), [2](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1471)) relating to it and [FAQs 2.21-23](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#why-does-dti-col-value-return-the-whole-of-dt-i-expected-either-no-visible-value-consistent-with---or-a-message-or-return-value-containing-how-many-rows-were-updated.-it-isnt-obvious-that-the-data-has-indeed-been-updated-by-reference.)